# Why Won't My Program Run in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8.1

I have a transportation program that we've used for 10 years. 
On this particular laptop it was working but stopped.

The behavior is this. When the app is opened, the program splash screen shows, then disappears, and no program opens. 
However,
The program shows running as a process, and not an app.

Inadvertently, Citrix Online Plugin also fails to open apps at the same time this occurred.

I have tried these in Compatibility Mode

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you try the [Application Compatibility Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825181.aspx). No one here can pinpoint what *exactly* is wrong with the app, but this is what the ACT was designed for. I'll also point out common issues:

- Permissions (either file/folder, or registry)
- UAC

You can't really work around the second one, but the ACT can provide you 'shims' that are sort of like patches in certain cases.

Also, as Evan pointed out, [ProcMon](http://live.sysinternals.com/) is a wealth of information in regards to what a particular program/process is doing. It doesn't take much ramp up time to learn the basics of how to use it, but it's something that can be used over and over, can actually narrow down root problems.

Comment: The ACT is nice for actually solving problems, but it doesn't do a lot to tell you what the problem is. I'd use Process Monitor for that.

Comment: +1 for ProcMon! It's amazing what you forget when you don't use it in a while. I got stories about ProcMon....